# Memory Profiling: How to detect which application/package is consuming too much memory

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory-leaks, profiling, memory-management

I have a situation here at work where we run a Java EE server with several applications deployed on it. Lately, we've been having frequent OutOfMemoryException's. We suspect some of the apps might be behaving badly, maybe leaking, or something.

The problem is, we can't really tell which one. We have run some memory profilers (like YourKit), and they're pretty good at telling what classes use the most memory. But they don't show relationships between classes, so that leaves us with a situation like this: We see that there are, say, lots of Strings and int arrays and HashMap entries, but we can't really tell which application or package they come from.

Is there a way of knowing where these objects come from, so we can try to pinpoint the packages (or apps) that are allocating the most memory?

Comment: Have you attached profilers to the individual apps? Or just to the app server?

Comment: Do you have a way to split them up on a test server.. give each a smaller max heap... and watch to see which one explodes?

Comment: you can also enable the GC logs and look at the size of young/old areas of the heap. run the JVM with "-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCDetails XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps –Xloggc:PATH_FROM_ROOT/gclog.log" for starters

Comment: @Jeff Storey: We have attached the profilers (YourKit and JRockit Mission Control) to the JVMs themselves. How could I go about attaching a profiler to specific apps inside an app server? That could certainly help.


@bwawok: Yes, we've thought about that option as well, though it would require some setup and calibration: We don't know how much memory our apps would need (even when well-behaved)


@josek: We're enabling gc logs right now, though we have no experience in analysing them.

Comment: @malvim. It might be tough to attach them to the app server while they are all running. Could you run one at a time in the app server and then attach to the app server?

Comment: @malvim: Once you get GC logs, run these through GCViewer first. Look at the bottom right corner for throughput (should be as high as possible) and memory footprint (should be low). an example is here http://jojovedder.blogspot.com/2009/06/slow-weblogic-part-6-jvm-heap-analysis.html

Answer (score 3):

There are several things that one could do in this situation:

- [Configure the Java EE application server to produce a heap dump on OOME](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/trouble/TSG-VM/html/clopts.html#gbzrr). This feature is available via a JVM parameter since the 1.5 days. Once a dump has been obtained, it can be analyzed offline, using tools like [Eclipse MAT](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). The important part is figuring out the dominator tree.
- Perform memory profiling on a test server; [Netbeans](http://profiler.netbeans.org/) is good at this. This is bound to take more time that the first when it comes to analyzing the root cause, since the exact conditions of memory allocation failure must be present. If you do have automated integration/functional tests, then deducing the root cause will be easier. The trick is to take periodic heap dumps, and analyze the classes that are contributing to the increase in heap consumption. There might not necessarily be a leak - it could be a case of insufficient heap size.

Answer (score 0):

A quick thought is that you probably can do some reflection, if you don't mind some performance trade-off....

Answer (score 0):

What I have found helpful is:

```
jmap -J-d64 -histo $PID
```

(remove the `-J-d64` option for 32-bit arch)

This will output something like this:

```
num     #instances         #bytes  class name
----------------------------------------------
1:       4040792     6446686072  [B
2:       3420444     1614800480  [C
3:       3365261      701539904  [I
4:       7109024      227488768  java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap$Entry
5:       6659946      159838704  java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock$Sync$HoldCounter
```

And then from there you can try to further diagnose the problem, doing diffs and what not to compare successive snapshots.

This will only pause the VM for a brief time, even for big heaps, so you can safely do this in production (during off-peak hours, hopefully :) )

Comment: Or just run `jvisualvm` if you're on a local machine (you can't do heap dumps remotely)